# Edit PDF in browser and save it back to server without downloading PDF on client machine

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser

I am building a web application which need to have inline editing of pdf files(Initially uploaded by application users to server) and save it back to the server.

Any ideas or reference docs will be great to start.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Editing of PDFs is not such a simple thing. Start with learning, what is iFilter and PDF.js

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I am using PDF.js to render the pdf and it is working fine. But the problem is I need to edit the pdf and save it to server.
Pdfium(chrome default pdf viewer to render/edit pdf files.) is open source but I am unable to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Editing PDF's is very tricky.

By doing a quick search you can I found something. You can try to convert the pdf to html and back after the edit. But in my experience working with html to pdf converters often involves loss of data and things looking not as clean as you made them.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX) tool

Comment: Can we use any open source code to inline editing of PDF files and save it to server?
I am able to render the PDF files using mozilla's PDF.js